# Find the spectrum of self-adjoint operator $T$ that satisfies $T^3+T^2+T+I=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $T:H \to H$ be a bounded operator such that $T$ is self-adjoint and also it satisfies the equation:
$$T^3+T^2+T+I=0$$

I want to find the spectrum $\sigma(T)$

By multiplying the equation with $T-I$, I got that $||T||=1$ (and also $||T^2||=1$, $||T^4||=1$).

Moreover, from the equation I also get: $0 = (T+I)(T^2+I)$

But I just don't see how from here I get to the spectrum of $T$ apart from $\lambda \not \in \sigma(T)$ if $|\lambda| > 1$.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the spectral mapping theorem, or some appropriate version of the spectral theorem?

Comment: Alternatively: if $T$ is self-adjoint then $T^2 + I$ is invertible...

Comment: I didn't learn this theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: start by showing that if $T$ is self-adjoint then $T^2+I$ is injective (in fact it is invertible).  As a start, suppose $(T^2+I)x = 0$ and look at $\langle (T^2+I)x, x \rangle=0$.  You should be able to manipulate this to conclude $x=0$.

Now as you have shown, $(T^2+I)(T+I) = 0$.  Given the injectivity, what does that say about $(T+I)x$ for arbitrary $x$?

This will tell you exactly what operator $T$ must be, and in particular it will be clear what its spectrum is.

Comment: I got to $T = -I$ so that means that $\sigma(T) = \{-1\}$ right?

Comment: @GabiG: Right!!

Comment: It's really elegant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the spectral mapping theorem for self-adjoint operators. Define $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ by $f(z)=z^3+z^2+z+1$. Then $f(\sigma(T))=\sigma(f(T))=\{0\}$. Thus you simply need to find the roots of $f$ (remember that self-adjoint operators can only have a non-empty real spectrum).

Comment: Specifically the *real* roots...

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, thank you. I have edited to make that clear.